# Setting terminal path for different env for anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using anaconda3 in windows. How can i set different terminal path for each environment. currently all point to same path.

eg:

- base (root) -> open console terminal from software point to C:/Users/User/Desktop
- locust -> open console terminal from software point to C:/locust

[image]

Comment: visit link  it will be helpul ... https://techras.wordpress.com/2019/02/13/how-to-change-the-default-working-directory-of-jupyter-and-jupyter-lab-in-anaconda-navigator-on-windows-environment/

Comment: @MuhammadRizwanMunawar That requires u to open the terminal and type "jupyter lab" which is diff from the behaviour i wanted, eg: open the terminal and it straight point to the directory